In factor analysis, what does the new model with a variable with low uniqueness removed say about the original model?
I am doing a factor analysis model using factanal in R:
$$X=Lf+\mathcal E. $$
When setting factors to be relatively large,
I received an error that the uniqueness of a variable (i.e.the estimation of $E(\epsilon_i^2)$) is close to zero.
Though I can fix it by setting extremely small lower value,
this post says it can cause problems.
Following the advice of this post, I tried to remove the variable $Y_i$ with low uniqueness,
and then the model works well.
However, I want to ask what does the new model with $Y_i$ removed imply about the original model?
For instance, if in the new model, $p$ factors fit well, can we assert $p+1$ factors fit well in the original model?

The low uniqueness itself implies that that variable makes it hard to find simple structure, because it loads on multiple factors. I'm not sure that this implies anything else about the full data set. It certainly doesn't imply that a model with one more factor would fit well - we know that isn't the case because, if it were true, the original attempt at factor analysis would have found that model.
Beyond that, I think the implications will be particular to your data and variables. One variable loads on more than one factor, at least in this data set . So, look at that variable and try to figure out whats going on.
As an aside, I think a lot of people neglect the "try to figure out what's going on" from their data analysis, and especially factor analysis. Many people expect the data analysis to give the answer; the one truth. This often does not happen. (I am not saying you are doing this, but many people do it; back when I was a consultant, my clients often wanted this from me).

Thank you! Would you please explain the meaning of “the variable loads on multiple factors“? I am sorry that I did not catch what this means.

When you do a factor analysis you seek "simple structure". How this is measured exactly varies by method, but the general idea is that you want each variable to load on only one factor: All the loadings should either be close to 1, -1, or 0.   But the FA program was unable to make this happen when the particular variable was included.

Thanks for your reply!
